# How to get transfer signatures of 0 decimal spl tokens?

Tags: javascript, solana, solana-web3js

I want to get spl token's, which 0 decimal, previous owner from the last owner.

When I check solscan's transfers tab I can see which wallets it has been transferred between. But on transactions tab I can only see the transaction which we are creating token account for other addresses.

**Transfer tab**
[image: Transfer tab]

**Transaction tab**
[image: Transaction tab]

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
const connection = new anchor.web3.Connection("https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net/", 'confirmed');
let txs=await connection.getTransaction("SPL TOKEN ADDRESS")
txs.map((element)=>{
  console.log(element.signature);
}); // Returns signatures where transaction tab.
```

Hence how can I get transfer list not transaction list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the previous owner of an SPL token account, you'll need to go through a few steps:

- Get all of the transaction signatures that reference the address of the account using `getSignaturesForAddress`: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress
- Get each of the transactions using `getTransaction` with `jsonParsed` encoding: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction
- Check the instructions at `['result']['transaction']['instructions']` and the inner instructions at `['result']['meta']['innerInstructions']` for `instruction_type: "setAuthority"`, and then see the `signers` for the old owner